# Jittery amimation curve in sequence editor

Tags: video

[image]

Greetings. Not sure if this is a Blender problem or my lack of knowledge. But here's the issue. I have a static image and I am trying to add a scale and position animation in the Video editor. The scale animation goes well - the image scales up and down predictably. But the position curve instead of a smooth line is jittery as if it weren't possible to scale across X and Y simultaneously. As a result the overall animation looks jerky. Is there a way to make the position animation smooth in the Video editor?

Comment: could be easing or a modifier.  what does the modifier tab show?

Comment: No easing or modifiers. Just plain "add keyframe" - and the same result with every animated image

Comment: Weird.  have you got an example you can share? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  also, might it be a 3.0alpha bug?  Have you / can you tried 2.93.4?

Comment: Yeah, tried in both the stable version and in 3.0. Tried to save it to share, but still file too large. I believe it is easy to reproduce with just a picture dragged and dropped onto a strip and animated. It happens every time I do it - so it should be the same with everyone else probably.